# Calculate mannwhitneyu over specified numpy axis

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, statistics, scipy

The Mann-Witney-U-test is the non-parametric equivalent to the t-test which can only be used for normally distributed data. In Scipy both test are available:

t-test: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_ind.html

Mann-Witney-U-test: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mannwhitneyu.html

While the ttest can be calculated over an e.g. 3d array by specifying the axis to perform the calculation, this seems not possible for the Mann-Witney-U-test?

```
import numpy
from scipy import stats

A1= numpy.random.normal(1,1,50).reshape(25, 2)
A2= numpy.random.normal(1,1,50).reshape(25, 2)
A3= numpy.random.normal(1,1,50).reshape(25, 2)
A4= numpy.random.normal(1,1,50).reshape(25, 2)
A5= numpy.random.normal(1,1,50).reshape(25, 2)
A = numpy.dstack((A1,A2,A3,A4,A5))

B1= numpy.random.normal(3,1,50).reshape(25, 2)
B2= numpy.random.normal(3,1,50).reshape(25, 2)
B3= numpy.random.normal(3,1,50).reshape(25, 2)
B4= numpy.random.normal(3,1,50).reshape(25, 2)
B5= numpy.random.normal(3,1,50).reshape(25, 2)
B = numpy.dstack((B1,B2,B3,B4,B5))

ttest_result = stats.ttest_ind(A,B,axis=2)
```

However specifying an axis for the Mann-Witney-U-test is not possible (like `stats.mannwhitneyu(A1,B1,axis=2)`)

Is there any possibility to run mannwhitneyu for a specifyed axis of a 3D array?
As mannwhitneyu() takes two arrays, numpy.apply_along_axis() can also not be used straight forward. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preform a similar operation on the 3rd axis in this example, I think you can do the following:

```
In [304]:

result = map(stats.mannwhitneyu, A.reshape(-1, A.shape[2]),B.reshape(-1, B.shape[2]))
u = np.array([item[0] for item in result]).reshape(A.shape[0], -1)
p = np.array([item[1] for item in result]).reshape(A.shape[0], -1)
In [305]:

u
Out[305]:
array([[ 0.,  4.],
       ...
       [ 1.,  2.]])
In [306]:

p
Out[306]:
array([[ 0.00609289,  0.04734647],
       ...
       [ 0.01078587,  0.01835693]])
```